# More than one User Profile Service Instance

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

We have SharePoint 2013 and running the following PS cmdlet:

**get-spserviceinstance | ? {$_.Typename -eq "User Profile Service"}**

We get the following result:

[image]

I am not sure why there are too many User Profile Services and two of them are Online. Does that look right? The reason I am asking, is that User Profile Sync has been running to day and when I click on stop, it is stuck in stopping.

Comment: how many servers do you have in your farm?

Comment: We have 7 servers

Comment: Stopping is different issue then the running instance of the User Profile Service...you marked a reply as anwser...did you fix the stopping issue or still stuck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have more copies of each services because your farm has more servers.

Try this to see the *online* services:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.Status -eq "online" } | Sort TypeName | Format-Table TypeName,Id,Status,Server
```

Take also a look here: [multiple results for each service instance](http://dinushaonline.blogspot.it/2013/08/why-do-i-get-multiple-results-for-get.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I know that it is tied to the number of servers we have in the farm and I did find out that we have two servers that have User Profile Service started. I don't know why we have 2, but I will stop one of them.